# C# - Concatenate inside a loop

Tags: c#, loops, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate inside a C# loop?  Below is my sample code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= metricCount; i++)
 {
      if (m.metrictNumber == i)
      {
         aggrgt.Add(new PlainBrgDataSummaryChartAggrgt
         {
            scoreWk6 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk6.metricScore1,
            scoreWk5 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk5.metricScore1,
            scoreWk4 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk4.metricScore1,
            scoreWk3 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk3.metricScore1,
            scoreWk2 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk2.metricScore1,
            scoreWk1 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk1.metricScore1

         });

       }
 }
```

What I want is to concatenate `metricScore1`.

Here's what I tried:

```
scoreWk6 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk6.metricScore + i,
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Update your question to include examples of how you've already tried to solve this question yourself... otherwise this will likely get down-voted.  Links to the C# documentation you've read would go a long way too (i.e. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What does your "attempt" have to do with concatenation? You are simply adding two values. And why should there be any issues with loops and "concatenation"? Did you get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work: scoreWk6 = scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk6.metricScore + i

Comment: what type is scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk6.metricScore ?

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work", what happens exactly?

Comment: What are `scoreWk6`, `scoreWk5` , .. ??

Comment: It's double. Here's the error:
does not contain a definition for 'metricScore' and no extension method 'metricScore' accepting a first argument of type  (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The type is double

Comment: Please show the declaration of `scoresPerDuration.scoresPerDuration.scoreWk6.scoreWk6` What is it? Is it a class?

Comment: var scoresPerDuration = repo.GetPlainBrgDataSummaryComplete(ProgramID, metricInfoProgram);

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. If you see numbers in variable names, it's probably wrong. Numbering your variables means you should have used a container type. Either an array or a list or anything else that supports going through it with a loop index or `foreach`.

So the answer is no. No, you cannot. You should change the types holding your data.